# Add a breadcrumb to a view page?

Tags: views, breadcrumbs

How can you just add a breadcrumb to views?
[Easy breadcrumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrtpG.png) leaves out views.
[Views breadcrumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8yCh.png) does not work correctly with Drupal 8.
Is there a simple way with hooks?

EDIT 2:
Maybe I mean something else?

In **Drupal 7** (with custom breadcrumb) it looks like this:
The view "Informationen" is called:

[image: The view is retrieved]

One node out of the view is called:

[image: node out of the view]

In **Drupal 8** (with Easy breadcrumb) it looks like this:
The view "Informationen" is called:
[image: D8 view called]

One node out of the view is called:

[image]

I hope I could explain the difference.

Comment: Place breadcrumb block from the menu : Structure > Block layout

  path: http://drupal-823.local/admin/structure/block

Comment: Do You mean the "Views breadcrumb" block? I could'nt find it in that way.

Comment: The default breadcrumb block ,you can add it to the required region by selecting Breadcrumbs from the Place block popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom module (use core >= 8.3). Use this code as a base to start:

**custom_breadcrumb.info.yml**

```
name: 'Custom breadcrumbs'
description: 'Custom breadcrumbs implementation'
package: 'Custom'
# core: 8.x
type: module

version: '8.x-1.0'
core: '8.x'
project: 'custom_breadcrumb'
datestamp: 1443649740
```

**custom_breadcrumb.services.yml**

```
services:
  custom_breadcrumb.breadcrumb_views:
    class: Drupal\custom_breadcrumb\Breadcrumb\ViewsBreadcrumbBuilder
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 1 }
```

**src/Breadcrumb/ViewsBreadcrumbBuilder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;

use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\LinkGeneratorTrait;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Link;

class ViewsBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {
  use LinkGeneratorTrait;
  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    // This breadcrumb apply only for some views.
    $parameters = $route_match->getParameters()->all();

    if (isset($parameters['view_id'])) {

       $views_id = array(
         'VIEW_MACHINE_NAME_1',
         'VIEW_MACHINE_NAME_2',
       );

       if (in_array($parameters['view_id'], $views_id)) {
         return TRUE;
       }
       return FALSE;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    // Breadcrumbs set up (cache settings are so important!).
    $breadcrumb = new \Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb();
    $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(["url"]);
    $breadcrumb->addCacheTags(["view_id:{$parameters['view_id']}"]);

    $parameters = $route_match->getParameters()->all();
    if (isset($parameters['view_id'])) {
      if ($parameters['view_id'] == 'VIEW_MACHINE_NAME_1') {
         $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute(t('VIEWS NAME 1'), '<none>'));
      }
      else if ($parameters['view_id'] == 'VIEW_MACHINE_NAME_2') {
        $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute(t('VIEWS NAME 2'), '<none>'));
      } 
    }

    // Reverse order for this to work!!!.
    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Home'), '<front>'));
    return $breadcrumb;
  }
}
```

Remember to replace **VIEW_MACHINE_NAME_1** and **VIEW_MACHINE_NAME_2** with the machine name of your views. Also replace **VIEWS NAME 1** and **VIEWS NAME 2** with the breadcrumb title you want for each view.

Comment: Thanks, i want to try it. This is not yet my level, I am very excited to do that.

Comment: I've tried it. Nothings happens.
The module is installed, machine names und view name are changed. No reaction. I can not debug this, unfortunately, a pity.
Thanks again.

Comment: Have you altered the 4 variables I told you at the bottom of my answer? Do you know how to find the machine name of a view? If you edit it then you will find the machine name on the URL. For example, the machine name for the admin content view is `content` given this URL: `admin/structure/views/view/content`. Also, you can debug my module if you enable the contrib Devel module together with its submodule "Devel kint". Then, anywhere on the code do `kint($VARIABLE_TO_DEBUG);`. Finally, make sure all files have their correct extension and make sure the Breadcrumb builder is under src/Breadcrumb.

Comment: Yes. I edited my question with images.

Comment: Which exact version of Drupal 8 are you using? The code I shared to you is working fine on a Drupal 8.3.0-beta1 Once enabled, have you rebuild the cache?

Comment: I have checked out all you have done and all seems to be fine. Maybe you can play altering the priority on custom_breadcrumb.services.yml

Comment: I' using 8.2.7, test on 8.3.0  I can also do.

Comment: Ok, I just tried on 8.2.6 and it doesn't work. So I updated it to 8.3.0-rc2 and it started to work. If you wish to upgrade yours do this from command line: 1) composer update 2) drush pm-update drupal-8.3.0-rc2  Make sure you are on drupal root directory.

Comment: in 8.3.0 rc1 I've got the wrong order: "Alle Informationen >> Startseite".

Comment: Then you can try to reorder the `$breadcrumb->addLink();` calls on build function. Anyway, I think on April 5 we will see 8.3.0 final release.

Comment: Also, if you use this custom module, disable any breadcrumb module that may overlap.

Comment: As a minor update from 8.2.7 to 8.3 there will be the simple core update possible as usual?  I have no ssh to my site.

Comment: Yes, when 8.3.0 is released I think you will be able to do a simple core update. Please, if you find my awser useful upvote and/or mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Test-Installation: 827 ->update 830rc2 -> success. looks nice.
My which above (2'nd picture) did You've  seen? Is this correctly this, what Custom breadcrumb does?

Comment: With "custom breadcrumbs" you are only doing the "Startseite > Informationen" stuff. If you want to customize node breadcrumbs you should create a new file with your NodeBreadcrumbBuilder.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. NodeBreadcrumbBuilder: How do I get there ?
Excuse me, I'm so unaware.

Comment: Just copy your ViewsBreadcrumbBuilder as NodeBreadcrumbBuilder and then modify the applies and build functions. Also remember to declare the new builder into custom_breadcrumb.services.yml. I give you an example doing breadcrumbs on taxonomies: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230722/drupal-8-how-to-do-a-custom-taxonomy-breadcrumb

Comment: For me in Drupal 9 it doesn't work either.
I tried to set a breakpoint, but it does not come inside the 'applies' function.

Comment: In build() on calling `$breadcrumb->addCacheTags(["view_id:{$parameters['view_id']}"]);` the $parameters is not yet defined.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to  Block layout page  http://drupal-823.local/admin/structure/block
- Select Place block in your required region for eg : content.
- Search for breadcrumbs on the popup.
- Click Place block button

You can restrict the access to the view by configuring the pages section.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Thank You. I did so. The system block breadcrumb is already enabled.
Btw: which admin theme do you use? It looks nice and better than seven.
Regards
Frank

Comment: Admin theme is  Seven. Also enabled the checkbox for : 
Use the administration theme when editing or creating content

Comment: It is an Adminimal theme