# Views breadcrumb

Tags: views, 8, breadcrumbs

I need to have breadcrumb builder that will make all "News" nodes appear as breadcrumb children of a View we've created at /news

I did follow this post : [Add a breadcrumb to a view page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231874/add-a-breadcrumb-to-a-view-page)

But it doesen't work, the module is installed with no error but no change on my breadcrumb, i did a simple **die;** in modules/custom_modal/src/Controller/CustomModalController.php

```
public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
 print_r("OK");
 die;
```

But no success .. and no error, i can't explain that, so any help is welcome

Comment: You are sure you followed the example in the referenced answers? A controller is not a breadcrumb service. Apart from this fact you may have to adapt the priority of the service later. 1 as used within the linked answer seems a little low. And if you want your breadcrumb builder service to run before others, it needs to have a higher priority than they do.

Comment: Yes i did and i'have adapt the priority service ( increase at 100) `class ViewsBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {
  use LinkGeneratorTrait;
  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    print_r("OK");
    die;`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using "Easy Breadcrumb": https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb.
Make sure your news articles geth the path of /news/my-news-article, and the easy breadcrumb module will automatically add correct breadcrumb of *> news > my news article*.

> Easy Breadcrumb takes advantage of the work you've already done for >generating your paths' alias, while it naturally encourages the creation >of semantic and consistent paths. This modules is currently available for >Drupal 7 and 8.

Comment: I use Easy Breadcrumb but i can not use it with my views cause my news node don't have menu entries .. so if i write a path alias ( myview/my article_1) i can not edit anymore in bo ( page not found so i have to correct path to node/num_of_my_news/?edit?destination=node/num_of_my_news). That's why im looking for custom solution ... to rewrite breadcrum for specific views